# Generate .NET Assemblies from Iron Python

Tags: .net, assemblies, ironpython

I have a Iron Python script that I want to run and then have the ipy interpreter output an assembly that I can run on other machines. How do I do that? Is there a switch I can pass to ipy.exe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a tool that ships with IronPython called Pyc or the Python Command-Line Compiler. If you installed the latest version 2.6 of IronPython, then `pyc.py` will be available at `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.6\Tools\Scripts` or wherever you installed IronPython on your system. If you have earlier versions of IronPython then `pyc.py` will be available as a separate download in the samples package.

With `pyc.py` you can create console or Windows assemblies from your python scripts. Basic usage looks like this:

```
ipy pyc.py /out:myprogram.exe /main:mainfile.py /target:exe program.py support.py
```

The above will generate an assembly called `myprogram.exe` (/out) which is a console application (/target) and will execute the code in `mainfile.py` first (/main) and will also include code from `program.py` and `support.py` in the assembly.

Comment: 11 years later. I was getting a "The system cannot find the file specified" error. I fixed by removing "/out:myprogram.exe" from the command line. This causes ipyc.exe to use the default output filename of main.exe.

Answer (score 10):

### Using SharpDevelop

One way to is to use [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/), it builds assemblies (executables and class libraries) easily.

The process is straightforward:

- Create a Python solution (Choices include: Class lib, Console or Windows application)
- Write your Python code as normal
- Build your solution or project

The .exe and .dll files will be in the relevant build output directory (Debug or Release).

### Using pyc.py

Another way is to the IronPython command line compiler script called **pyc.py.**

The compiler script can be found in the directory:
`[IP_install_dir]\Tools\Scripts`

Usage:
`ipy.exe pyc.py /main:Program.py Form.py /target:winexe`

**Note**:  To get the compiled exe to run you will need the following files in the same directory as your executable:

```
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute.dll
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also compile by using

```
import clr
clr.CompileModules("foo.dll","foo.py")
```

for asp.net, if you use pyc.py to compile, you wont be able to import the modules.They expect to fix that in 2.6.2 or later