# How to Create a python Dll file that should be used in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, python, ironpython

I have to create a win32 python dll file which can used in C#.Net code.
And access the classes & functions present in the dll file through C#.
*Is there any way to create a win32 python dll?*

Please help me out....

Comment: Are you trying to put Python code in a DLL and call this from C#?

Comment: For .NET, you need IronPython, not "ordinary" Python.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437306/generate-net-assemblies-from-iron-python

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython).

Comment: Yes I am trying to put Python code in a DLL and call this from C#.

Comment: Pyrex + ctypes appears to be the answer, but a COM server might be more convenient than a win32 dll.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your Python sources to a DLL with `pyc.py`, in the Samples directory of IronPython. However, you can't load this DLL from C# directly - you'll still need to host IronPython, but then you can reference the DLL with the IronPython engine and import from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try do some investigation about Pyrex. I'm not sure if it will solve your issue, but at least I seen that some guys was trying to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any DLL, you just need to load your Python sources using IronPython

Comment: So, how can we hide the python sources. I have to bundle it in the C# .dll. Is it possible?

Comment: Absolutely, include the source as a string resource in your assembly.